# flag = 1 if there is a change from 1 to 0 in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, logic

Is there a quick way to assign `flag` to 1 if for a particular `variable` there is a change from 1 to 0, so that I get the below. This `variable` is only allowed to go from from 0 to 1, it is not possible to see 1 to 0 and I would like to flag if that happens.

```
organisation | time       | variable | flag
A            | 2020-01-01 | 0        | 0
A            | 2020-02-01 | 0        | 0   
A            | 2020-03-01 | 0        | 0   
A            | 2020-04-01 | 1        | 0       
A            | 2020-05-01 | 1        | 0      
A            | 2020-06-01 | 1        | 0     
A            | 2020-07-01 | 1        | 0    
B            | 2020-01-01 | 0        | 1      
B            | 2020-02-01 | 0        | 1     
B            | 2020-03-01 | 0        | 1     
B            | 2020-04-01 | 1        | 1       
B            | 2020-05-01 | 0        | 1      
B            | 2020-06-01 | 1        | 1     
B            | 2020-07-01 | 1        | 1
```

**Edit:**

**Extra question:** what if variable is 0,1,2 and I now want to flag if there is a change from 2 to 1?

```
organisation | time       | variable | flag
A            | 2020-01-01 | 0        | 0
A            | 2020-02-01 | 0        | 0   
A            | 2020-03-01 | 0        | 0   
A            | 2020-04-01 | 1        | 0       
A            | 2020-05-01 | 1        | 0      
A            | 2020-06-01 | 2        | 0     
A            | 2020-07-01 | 2        | 0    
B            | 2020-01-01 | 0        | 1      
B            | 2020-02-01 | 0        | 1     
B            | 2020-03-01 | 0        | 1     
B            | 2020-04-01 | 1        | 1       
B            | 2020-05-01 | 2        | 1      
B            | 2020-06-01 | 1        | 1     
B            | 2020-07-01 | 1        | 1
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the example. Are 1 -> NA transitions also supposed to trigger the flag?  Is the flag supposed to be 1 for all values after the first 'forbidden' transition?

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. No, apologies I have removed NAs from my question, I did a mistake. The flag is supposed to be 1 only when there is a transition from 1 to 0. And once that happens at least once per organisation, flag is supposed to be 1 for all values across that organisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying your problem in your comment and edited question. Here is a solution that I think will work with your actual data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            organisation = c("A","A","A","A",
                             "A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                    time = c("2020-01-01",
                             "2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-04-01","2020-05-01",
                             "2020-06-01","2020-07-01","2020-01-01",
                             "2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-04-01","2020-05-01",
                             "2020-06-01","2020-07-01"),
                variable = c(0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,
                             1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,0L,1L,1L),
                    flag = c(0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
                             0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L)
      )

df %>%
  group_by(organisation) %>%
  mutate(flag = +any(lag(variable, default = 0) == 1 & variable == 0))
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#> # Groups:   organisation [2]
#>    organisation time       variable  flag
#>    <chr>        <chr>         <int> <int>
#>  1 A            2020-01-01        0     0
#>  2 A            2020-02-01        0     0
#>  3 A            2020-03-01        0     0
#>  4 A            2020-04-01        1     0
#>  5 A            2020-05-01        1     0
#>  6 A            2020-06-01        1     0
#>  7 A            2020-07-01        1     0
#>  8 B            2020-01-01        0     1
#>  9 B            2020-02-01        0     1
#> 10 B            2020-03-01        0     1
#> 11 B            2020-04-01        1     1
#> 12 B            2020-05-01        0     1
#> 13 B            2020-06-01        1     1
#> 14 B            2020-07-01        1     1
```

Extra question:

The logic is the same - if the current value for variable equals 1 and the previous value ("lagged value") for variable equals 2 (i.e. a change from 2 to 1), flag equals 1 for that whole group:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            organisation = c("A","A","A","A",
                             "A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                    time = c("2020-01-01",
                             "2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-04-01","2020-05-01",
                             "2020-06-01","2020-07-01","2020-01-01",
                             "2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-04-01","2020-05-01",
                             "2020-06-01","2020-07-01"),
                variable = c(0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,
                             2L,2L,0L,0L,0L,1L,2L,1L,1L),
                    flag = c(0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
                             0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L)
      )

df %>%
  group_by(organisation) %>%
  mutate(flag = +any(lag(variable, default = 0) == 2 & variable == 1))
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#> # Groups:   organisation [2]
#>    organisation time       variable  flag
#>    <chr>        <chr>         <int> <int>
#>  1 A            2020-01-01        0     0
#>  2 A            2020-02-01        0     0
#>  3 A            2020-03-01        0     0
#>  4 A            2020-04-01        1     0
#>  5 A            2020-05-01        1     0
#>  6 A            2020-06-01        2     0
#>  7 A            2020-07-01        2     0
#>  8 B            2020-01-01        0     1
#>  9 B            2020-02-01        0     1
#> 10 B            2020-03-01        0     1
#> 11 B            2020-04-01        1     1
#> 12 B            2020-05-01        2     1
#> 13 B            2020-06-01        1     1
#> 14 B            2020-07-01        1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks @jared_mamrot, your solution is not yet working with my data at the moment. I did a mistake in my question and I do not have NAs for "variable" so it simplifies the issue. But I do not understand how your code takes into account organisation? The flag is supposed to be 1 only when there is a transition from 1 to 0. And once that happens at least once per organisation, flag is supposed to be 1 for all values across that organisation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @DanielaRodrigues, it looks like I completely misunderstood what you wanted. I've edited my answer to provide a likely solution.